# Google Cloud KMS encryption got very different results between command line and java code

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-sdk

I am a beginner to google cloud. I have a java code which uses KMS to encrypt some credential information. At last it returns the cyphertext (a String object), which is what i need. It gives me something like this:

`CiQAUxKMC06hZ7cuhlqdQQPGdNJqotwoKlSzjKmr+kwR3iMLg04SZABqmWMTCukKk0EVIDa1PpqqSIszczXGvt+nQN/jpV3DLEjXH3xkzdL0an9kiRIfLHryhcFwaYt/DczI4sy4VdZSoyKcszzZyGdVjISsyIbMnYINuqme1sa7GqLM98cXfnYzHjE=`

```
EncryptResponse response = kms.projects().locations().keyRings().cryptoKeys()
            .encrypt(resourceName, request)
            .execute();
return response.getCiphertext();
```

Now I also want a bootstrap script that could do the similar thing. However, when I use command line as follows. The content in the encryption.txt file is not nice looking as a String, but some unicode characters. Is there a way I could achieve the above nice encryption string by using gcloud kms command line?

`export ENCRYPTION=$(gcloud kms encrypt --location=global --keyring=$KEYRING --key=$KEY --plaintext-file=text.txt --ciphertext-file=encryption.txt)`

Comment: Please don't use bold to shout. Please do format code areas - using back-ticks, for example.
The result that you are showing is in a format known as quoted-printable.

Comment: Apparently the `response.getCiphertext();` returns encoded (base64) response, while the commands ine writes binary data. Maybe you could use `base64` commands encode and decode the ciphertext

Comment: base64 works fine . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud KMS uses Base64-encoded AES-256 encryption [keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/using-customer-supplied-keys).
You should be able to decode the cyphertext using the base64 library.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things.
One is the API Call.

```
curl -s -X POST "https://cloudkms.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT>/locations/<LOCATIO >/keyRings/<KEY_RING>/cryptoKeys/<KEY>:encrypt" \ 
-d "{\"plaintext\":\"$(echo hello world | base64)\"}" \
-H "Authorization:Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \  -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

This API call gives base64 encoded value of cipher text which is readable.

Another way is yo use SDK (here only talking about java SDK)

`EncryptResponse.getCiphertext()` will return gibberish, you have to encode it using base64 to get the readable cipher text

```
String cipherText = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(response.getCiphertext().toByteArray()))
```

output of above string and cipher text received by API will match.

Similarly while decoding using KMS, API will give base64 decoded value of text on the other hand you have to manually convert output of SDK call to string by decoding

```
 String decodedText = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(key)
```